# A field in my Django model already exists in the PostgreSQL database

Tags: django, postgresql, model, migration, conflict

I have a Django app with a model MyModel and some field my_field.  My PostgreSQL database already has a field of that name under the mymodel table, since it was added manually in the past.  When I make migrations, Django generates an AddField operation, which is in conflict.  Currently I manually edit every generated migration to remove the conflict.

Is there a way to tell Django that the field already exists?

Unfortunately this is a live product, so I cannot lose any data.

Comment: Generate the migration that adds the field and then run `python manage.py migrate <app_name> <migration_name> --fake` to mark the migration as applied without actually running it

Answer (score 1):

> Generate the migration that adds the field and then run python manage.py migrate <app_name> <migration_name> --fake to mark the migration as applied without actually running it

Thank you Iain Shelvington.